# How to add a blank google calendar

Tags: javascript, html, google-calendar-api

I want to add a google calendar to my website, I don't want to add a calendar from my google account. I want a blank calendar to which I can add items using JS.

What I want to do is have the user enter some data, then once they navigate to the calendar page it will show those items, they should be the only people to see it. It's like a person calendar that should be dinamically created when the page is loading.

Is this possible ?

Comment: The part I struggle with is adding the calendar to the page, the google api sample requires auth, which seems pointless.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want a Google calendar, but just a calendar implementation in your site.  I'm not sure why you are working with the Google calendar API.

Comment: @Brian That's a good point, I didn't really consider that.